# Как добавить приставку к логам?

Tags: bash, linux

Я запускаю чужой скрипт script.sh. Он выводит какие-то свои логи. Как сделать так, чтобы к каждой строчке скрипта добавлялся префикс, например, [script]. То есть оригинальный лог

```
строкастрока
```

а измененный

```
[script] строка[script] строка
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Он пишет логи сам? Или пользуется syslog?

Comment: Он пишет лог сам. Это выглядит так: `./script.sh >> log`

Comment: echo 'line' | awk '{print "[script]" $0}' > /tmp/out.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно делать так

```
./script.sh | while read line; do echo "[script] $line"; done >> log
```

Префикс в цикле добавляется к каждой строке.

Comment: Это работает!